# how to display text in 2 columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using TinyMCE in ModX CMS.

Do you have any idea how can I display text written in wysiwyg in 2 columns, and if possible coulms should be similar height, width must be the same.

There is no option (button) to insert table using TinyMCE.

1 option is to click on html icon and create table with 2 columns, but person who will manage the content won't be able to do it.

I thought it could be JavaScript, jQuery maybe. But how will I count text and split it in the right place. Any ideas?

Comment: Show us some code and maybe a fiddle.

To play well with textareas, try using a [contenteditable](http://html5demos.com/contenteditable) div ;).

Comment: sorry, but I havent any code for that yet. I just need some idea how to do it. I will have a look on your link. Thx

Comment: Yes but you have to do some researches to be helped here...

Answer (score 1):

You can place an external button with the following:

```
<button onclick="tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent',false,'<table><tr><td>TEXT</td><td>TEXT</td></tr></table>');return false;">Insert table</button>
```

This will insert the code on the cursor position. You can take a look here too for more info:

[TinyMCE Command Identifiers](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Command_identifiers)